# Altitude to the Hypotenuse Proportions

Tags: geometry

Could someone please assist me with the following problems?  I have tried all of the theorems on them and they do not work.

[image]

Also, my professor told me that in: $ \frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{x} $ that $x$ must always be $a$ because you must have one cross-product be equal to each other (meaning the same variable).  Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have similar triangles, so should identify matching parts for these ratios.  On the left on the first you are considering the triangle with sides $r,h,a$.  What is the similar triangle with $a$ the shortest side.

For your last question, how can $\frac 13=\frac 4{12}$ fit into this?

Comment: So, would $\frac{r}{h}= \frac{a}{b} $?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank you! That incorrect statement from my professor sent me on a path to oblivion!

Answer (score 0):

"The height to the hypotenuse in a straight-angle triangle divides the triangle in two little triangles simmilar with each other and with the bigger triangle"

From the above, and denoting the big triangle vertices by $\;A,B,C\;$ (beginning from the rightmost one and clockwise) and the intersection point of the height with the hyponetuse by $\;D\;$, we get

$$\Delta ABC\sim\Delta CBD\sim \Delta ACD$$

so, for example:

$$\frac rh=\frac{BD}{CD}=\frac{BC}{AC}=\frac ab$$

and etc.